# Knockout and MVC2: sending model to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, knockout.js

I'm having problem with sending json from knockout to mvc2 controller action. 
Here is what I have in my View:

```
var ViewModel = {
            FirstName: ko.observable("FirstName"),
            LastName: ko.observable("LastName"),
            Save: function () {
                ko.utils.postJson(location.href, this);
            }
}
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

I have an action in controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult SomeAction(MyModel model) {
        //do smth
        return View(registrationModel);
}
public class MyModel {
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

The problem is that i'm getting string values quoted, like "\"FirstName\"", and I know that there is some way to avoid that(work with JSON.stringify in MVC3).
I've tried the following:

```
ko.utils.postJson(location.href, JSON.stringify({model: this});
```

also

```
var json = JSON.stringify({
FirstName: this.FirstName(),
LastName: this.LastName()
});
ko.utils.postJson(location.href, JSON.stringify({model: json});
```

or

```
ko.utils.postJson(location.href, json);
```

In all these 3 options I get model = null, or all the values null in Controller.

Maybe someone has done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that in order for the MVC object mapping to work you need to set the content type of the POST to be "application/json; charset=utf-8". I've never done this using ko.utils.postJson() before but here's a working example using jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: ko.toJSON(ViewModel),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
        },
        error: function (response, errorText) {
        }
    });
```

Note I'm using `ko.toJSON` to serialize the model as JSON.